# What book contains all possible Euclidic triangular constructions?

Tags: reference-request, triangles

It was 1993 when a Math teacher showed us guys a (new?) book that contained all possible Euclidic triangular constructions.

I was flashed then. The idea that you can just enlist all elements of a triangle (sides, angles, height, median lines...) and then just enlist all the possible constructions in a combinatorial way seemed powerful and closing to me. So recently I tried to find this book again.

Unfortunately, it seems difficult to find. I find many papers and books about triangles but not just the big list of all possible constructions.

```
Question: Do you know about this book containing all possible triangular constructions, 
can you help me finding it?
```

Comment: Might be **Wernick's List**. It has $560$ constructions. Here's the [pdf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2016volume16/FG201610.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwicss-5o77rAhWuzDgGHXOJCKcQFjABegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw3SLfSlKpK08nbbqEWOaZvz).

Comment: Thank you very much @SarGe. I remember the classification in **r**edundant, **l**ocus dependet, **s**olvable and **u**nsolvable. So even it is not precicely the mentioned book, it is what I wanted to find. If you write an anywer, I'll upvote.